# Read a log file in R

Tags: json, r, logfile

I'm trying to read a log file in R.
It looks like an extract from a JSON file to me, but when trying to read it using jsonlite I get the following error message: "Error: parse error: trailing garbage".

Here is how my log file look like:

```
{"date":"2017-05-11T04:37:15.587Z","userId":"admin","module":"Quote","action":"CreateQuote","identifier":"-.admin1002"},
{"date":"2017-05-11T05:12:24.939Z","userId":"a145fhyy","module":"Quote","action":"Call","identifier":"RunUY"},
{"date":"2017-05-11T05:12:28.174Z","userId":"a145fhyy","license":"named","usage":"External","module":"Catalog","action":"OpenCatalog","identifier":"wks.klu"},
```

Has you can see, the column name is precised directly in front of the content for each line (e.g: "date": or "action":)
And some line can skip some columns and add some other.

What I want to get as output would be to have 7 columns with the corresponding data filled in each:

```
date

userId

license

usage

module

action

identifier
```

Does anyone has a suggestion about how to get there?

Thanks a lot in advance

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Thanks everyone for your answers. Here are some precisions about my issue:

The data that I gave as example in an extract of one of my log files. I've got a lot of them that I need to read as one unique table. 
I haven't added any commas or anything to it.

@r2evans
I've tried the following:

`Log3 <-read.table("/Projects/data/analytics.log.agregated.2017-05‌​-11.log")`      `jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(gsub(",$","",Log3)))`

It returns the following error:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text. 
                  c(17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 2 
(right here) ------^
```

I'm not sure how to use `sed -e 's/,$//g' infile > outfile` and `Sys.which("sed")`, that something I'm not familiar with. I'm looking into it, but if you have anymore precisions to give me about the usage of it that would be great.

Comment: If this is the complete data then put the whole string inside of brackets: "["+<log-file>+"]".

Comment: This should give you the desired result: `jsonlite::fromJSON(txt=paste0("[",'yourtext',"]",)`

Comment: A logfile written in JSON begs the use of [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/), allowing the use of `jsonlite::stream_in(file("logfile.json"))`. Are the trailing commas something you added to try to get it to parse correctly? An alternative to AGore's suggest is `jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(gsub(",$", "", txt)))` where `txt` is the vector of lines.

Comment: or `ndjson::stream_in(…)` but those commas are going to kill the ndjson parsing

Comment: If you're going for speed with large amounts of data, I'd suggest hrbrmstr's `ndjson` with a pre- and before-R processing with something like `sed -e 's/,$//g' infile > outfile` ... other ways certainly exist, this will be among your fastest. You could call that from R (assuming `Sys.which("sed")` finds it) if needed. (linux/macos likely have `sed` already; windows with Git-for-Windows or Rtools will have it, too.)

Comment: Thanks a lot or your answers but unfortunately nothing worked.
The data that I gave as example in an extract of one of my log files. I've got a lot of them that I need to read as one unique table.

@r2evans I've tried the following:
Log3 <-read.table("/Projects/data/analytics.log.agregated.2017-05-11.log")
jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(gsub(",$","",Log3)))
It returns this error:
    Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       c(17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 2
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: That kind of message works much better edited into the question, not as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I'll modify that.

Comment: As your error doesn't seems to match any of your sample line, it's hard to guess what could turn wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

I have saved your example as a file "test.json" and was able to read and parse it like this:

```
library(jsonlite)

rf <- read_file("test.json")
rfr <- gsub("\\},", "\\}", rf)
data <- stream_in(textConnection(rfr))
```

It parses and simplifies into a neat data frame exactly like you want. What I do is look for "}," rather than ",$", because the very last comma is not (necessarily) followed by a newline character(s).

However, this might not be the best solution for very large files.. For those you may need to first look for a way to modify the text file itself by getting rid of the commas. Or, if that's possible, ask the people who exported this file to export it in a normal ndjson format:-)